# howto query table per hierarchy which subclasses are present

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

a simple example

```
abstract class Car
{
    public virtual long SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

class Mercedes : Car { }

class Fiat : Car { }

class Toyota : Car { }
```

now i want to query for which types inheriting from car are on stock. How to do this? Or is my design flawed.

example

```
session.Save(new Mercedes() { SerialNumber = 1 });
session.Save(new Mercedes() { SerialNumber = 2 });
session.Save(new Toyota() { SerialNumber = 1 });

// later
var models = session2.Query<Car>().SelectDistinct(car => car.GetType().Name);

showModelComboBox.Items = models;
```

Comment: I take it `Stock` is a property defined in `Car`. Does `session.QueryOver<Car>().Where(w=>w.InStock)` not work?

Comment: Is this your actual domain? It doesn't look like a good use case for inheritance.

Comment: If property you want to filter by is in your `car` class then it is possible

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon my domain is actually quite similar. Dependent on the type there is a lot of business logic attached and many columns are only valid for specific types. However i have a use case where i should filter on the existing records in the database and want to show only options which actually are in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the following works:

```
var models = session.Query<Car>().Select(x => x.GetType().Name).ToList();
```

...and you can apply `Distinct` later... but it's actually fetching the whole entities.
Not good.

It looks like `Distinct` can't be applied to a `GetType` expression.

Now, you can do the following:

```
var models = session.CreateQuery("select c.class from Car c").List();
```

It will return the raw discriminators, which is not ideal, but it works.

Comment: actually the schema is a classic TPH with half the columns common for all rows and then dependent on a type column columns for individual rows. Since even one-to-many are dependent on the type i thought it would be a good idea.